# scripting bash for loop awk output in argument

Tags: linux, bash, shell

im writing some bash exercises, this in particular wants to check all the files named file-a(sonenumber) and move it to directory named dirA
But there's some problem with for loop
i can do that without for loop just simply writing

```
mv $(ls -la | awk '$9 - /-a[0-9]+/ {print $9}') dirA
```

but i wanna do it with a for and i cant do that
there's the script

```
FILES=(ls -la | awk '$9 - /-a[0-9]+/ {print $9}')

for arg in "$FILES"
do
       mv $arg dirA
done
```

Comment: Did you really mean to **subtract** a regexp from `$9`? I suspect `$9 -` should be `$9 ~`

Comment: Thanks to add sample input and expected output

Answer (score 3):

No need a for loop, just a [shell `glob`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob):

```
mv -- *-a[0-9]* dirA
```

If you insist for a loop:

```
files=( *-a[0-9]* )

for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    mv "$f" dirA/
done
```

or

```
for f in *-a[0-9]*; do
    mv "$f" dirA/
done
```

But **please**, avoid parsing `ls` output.

`ls` is a tool for interactively looking at directory metadata. Any attempts at parsing `ls` output with code are broken. Globs are much more simple AND correct: `for file in *.txt`. Read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

---

[Don't use UPPER case variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Comment: I think the wildcard should be `*-a[0-9]*`

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting `FILES` to the output of the command. For that, you need to use `$(command)`. To make it an array, wrap another set of `()` around that.

Then to loop over the array contents, use `"${FILES[@]}`.

I'm not sure why you're using `ls -la` when you could just use `ls -a`. Then each filename will be a single line, you don't have to extract `$9`.

```
FILES=($(ls -a | awk '/-a[0-9]+/'))

for arg in "${FILES[@]}"
do
       mv "$arg" dirA
done
```

However, it's best [not to parse the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).

Answer (score -6):

I modified your code to work in the for loop.

```bash
FILES=$(ls -la | awk  '/-a[0-9]+/ {print $9}') 
for arg in $FILES 
do 
  mv $arg dirA
done
```